# Tensions in a rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

If two tensions are acting on a rope such that they are equal (each is 10 N) and opposite (180 degrees) then what will be the total tension in the rope?
I cant seem to figure out if these two will cancel each other's effect and become zero or these will add up to make 20N tension.

Comment: More on forces and factors of two: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41291/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Imagine cutting the rope and holding one side of the cut such as the rope does not move. How much do you have to pull on it? It is 10N, and this is the definition of tension.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for the link but some people say it will be 10 and others say it will be 20 now what will be the specific and right answer is still undetermined ?

Comment: @ja72 I can't really understand what you are trying to tell me :(

Comment: Tension is defined as the force you need to apply to a part of the rope so it does not move.

Comment: @ja72 ah so I guess the tension in the string will be 10N because that is the force required so it remains in equilibrium,is that what you're trying to tell from that definition ?