# What will be the compression of a spring if two different forces act on it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, free-body-diagram

[image]

**QUESTION**

What will be the compression in this picture?

Many problems relating to springs are when one side of the springs are fixed and the other is free to deflect. But what happens when the spring is free to move on both sides? How does the kinematics of the spring change with respect to the different forces on the spring?

**TRIAL**

Generally, for any force $F1$ and $F2$ and a spring constant of $K$ the spring will compress by the formula:
$$\Delta x= \frac{min(F1,F2)}{K}$$ and it will accelerate by $$a=\frac{(F1-F2)}{m}.$$

Comment: More on forces and factors of two: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41291/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close this question. I think it is an excellent question! It's not a homework question, it does show some effort (a picture is worth a thousand words), it isn't off-topic. The solution can be surprising, as can be seen by the wrong answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong, because the acceleration will cause the spring to compress under its own inertia. I assume without loss of generality $F_1>F_2$. The balanced part of the forces will compress the spring as usual, the compression is
$$\Delta x_b=\frac{F_2}{k}.$$
The compression under acceleration is equivalent to the compression of the spring under its own weight in a gravitational field with gravitational acceleration $g=a=\frac{F_1-F_2}{m}$. The compression under acceleration is
$$\Delta x_a=\frac{ma}{2k}=\frac{F_1-F_2}{2k}.$$
The total compression is
$$\Delta x_\text{Total}=\Delta x_b +\Delta x_a=\frac{F_1+F_2}{2k}.$$

Note that this is the compression in the steady state, after the oscillations have settled down. If you apply these forces to a spring initially at rest, it will also start to oscillate.

Edit:
**Derivation of $\Delta x_a$**

Assume a spring in a gravitational field standing vertically on a desk. The spring will be compressed under its own weight. Divide the unstretched spring into infinitesimal segments dl. Each of these segments will compress a distance dx under the weight of all segments on top of it. The top segment has no weight above itself, so it is uncompressed. The segment at the bottom has the weight of the whole spring above, so it will compress the most. 
If we divide the spring into segments of length dl, the spring constant of each segment is $k'=k\frac{L}{dl}.$
The compression of each segment is 
$$dx=\frac{l/L\cdot mg}{k'}=\frac{lmg}{L^2k}dl.$$
Therefore
$$\Delta x_a=\int_0^L \frac{lmg}{L^2k}dl=\frac{mg}{2k}.$$

Comment: why did you add $/2$ for $\Delta Xa$

Comment: The extension/compression of a spring with mass m under its own weight is half as big, as the extension/compression you would get, if the whole mass m was hanging on one end. Maybe I should add a derivation of that to my answer.

Comment: @Socre I have added a derivation of that part.

Comment: wow! it actually makes sense, the compression of the spring is the average of the two different forces. If both forces are equal the compression comes from the average of the two forces which is either of the forces. But what happens if F2=0. then by your statement it would compress by F2/2k but intuitively it should be zero, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Socre In the case $F_2=0$ you have only a force on one side. This means the spring is accelerated and you get the result for an accelerated spring $\Delta x=\frac{F_2}{2k}=\frac{ma}{2k}$. The compression should not be zero! Imagine a spring in an accelerting rocket. The astronauts will be pushed into their seats, and a spring will compress for the same reason.

Comment: @Socre Sorry, I meant $\Delta x=\frac{F_1}{2k}=\frac{ma}{2k}$, if $F_2=0$.

Comment: it is a good argument, but i still am not entirely convinced. if the k value is 5N/cm and the spring is pushed by 5N on one side of the spring horizontally(assume gravity is in the Z direction (facing down from this page)). Then i doubt the spring will compress by 2.5cm. Also assume that the environment is vacuum (no viscous forces acts on the system) If can you direct me to a book where such problems are tackled that could also be a reference for me, that would be of great help.

Comment: @Socre So, you think if I hit the spring very hard on one side it wouldn't compress at all? That would be a very unphysical spring. I don't know any book with this specific problem. Why don't you do the experiment yourself. A cheap spring costs only a few dollars. The effect would be more visible with a low spring constant.

Comment: @Socre The spring would be compressed by 0.5 cm in your example.

Comment: I have been looking at your proof and i don't understand how you got $k'=\frac{dl*k}{L}$  when i tried it, i got the reverse, which is $k'=\frac{dl*k}{L}$.

Comment: the mass element just above the element spring should be $m*{\frac{L-l}{L}}$ but i ultimately got the same result when using the k' value you used. i just need to understand how the k' value is found.

Comment: @Socre To get k' you need to realize that the spring "constant" depends on the length of the spring. Imagine you hang two identical springs (sping constant k') in series and then you hang a weight on the spring. The force on each spring will be F=M*g. Each individual spring extends by x'=F/k', therefore the total extension of both springs is x=2*F/k'=F/k, so the new spring constant is k=k'/2. So if I cut a spring in half the spring constant is k'=2k. Similarly if I divide the spring in sections of length dl, I have L/dl sections, so the new spring constant is L/dl times larger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. The same is applicable for an object subject to compressive or elongative forces. The min. of the two forces causes elongation or compression in the body. The internal stress produced is same as that of the smaller force. The difference of two forces that is the net force causes the acceleration of the object. The same is the case with the spring.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case of the spring with two forces of the same magnitude acting, the force acting will be $2 N$ simply because that is the only existing compressing forces/ You could visualize this as the net force being zero implying that the spring remains stationary. However, since this is a spring we are talking about, the spring will get compressed in both directions.

Meanwhile in the first scenario, the net force is $2N$, but there is still compression across both ends due to both the forces acting on it (the $4N$ and $2N$).