# Collision of block and a spring system kept at rest

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, spring

A body of mass $m$ moving with velocity $v$ collides with a system of 2 blocks of each mass $m$ connected by a spring of spring constant $k$. All the three lie on the same plane (1D collision). There is no friction anywhere.Do the spring compress? . If yes then why? To compress or elongate a spring equal and opposite forces should be applied to opposite ends, then how could the spring compress. Please explain

Comment: Is any friction involved? Can all blocks be considered to be on a frictionless supporting surface?

Comment: No friction is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you tacitly set a colinear collision, if not let me know to modify the answer.

The spring will compress in a variety of modes.

-If the collision is elastic, the moving block will stop entirely after it hits the stationary block and give all its momentum (Newtons system of balls and cradle ) to stationary block and then that stationary block starts to move back with speed v and this will compress the spring and start to push the last block back. This will start a free vibration in the system of the spring and two blocks which will gradually slide away while vibrating.

-If the collusion is not elastic there will be some loss of kinetic energy of the moving block and it may recoil back while pushing the second block back and compressing the spring, or depending on the stiffness and length of spring it may become one with the two blocks and move and with them at least for the compression part of the vibration.

Comment: Sir it is elastic collision

Answer (score 0):

> Do the spring compress?

Yes.

> There is no friction any where. If yes then why?

Because the spring itself and the mass on its end have some inertia.

> To compress or elongate a spring equal and opposite forces should be applied to 
>   opposite ends, then how could the spring compress.

No, that is wrong. If a one sided force is applied to a spring, it will accelerate. An accelerated spring will compress, because each part of the spring has inertia/mass. I have answered a somewhat similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471673/what-will-be-the-compression-of-a-spring-if-two-different-forces-act-on-it/471720#471720).

Comment: I believe the spring will compress even if it is considered massless.

Comment: @BobD Hmm, thats an interesing thought. I think you're right, however the springs acceleration would be infinite and it would immediately reach the speed of light...

Comment: If you look at the two masses connected by the spring as a single elastically deformable mass you wouldn’t think of the elasticity property as something that “accelerates” would you?

Comment: @BobD Yes I would. The elasticity is a property of the body and the body is accelerating. Personally I think your way of thinking about it makes the problem harder to understand, not easier. But thats subjective of course.

Comment: I think it is the inertia of the mass that is critical here, not the  spring. But I understand there are more than one way of looking at things.

Comment: @BobD I think both are important, because even without the blocks a (non massless) spring would compress and oscillate. Of course in most real world cases, the springs mass would be much smaller than the masses of the blocks, which would make the springs mass negligible. I absolutely agree that the inertia of mass (either the springs or the blocks mass) is critical here. Thats what I said in my answer.

Comment: All I am saying is that it is not essential that we  consider the mass of the spring to solve the problem. But I'm going to leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the before the collision took place the mass $ m_{1} $ (which is just a designation for the block which collides with the other two blocks) had a velocity say $ v $ it can be assumed that the coefficient of restitution is  $ e $ such that $ 0≤e≤1 $ now using the conservation of momentum and equation of restitution we would have $ v_{2} = \frac { ( e+1)v}{2}  $ , where $ v_{2} $ denotes the velocity of the mass which initially collides with the moving block .  With this  now we shift to consider the centre of mass frame of the two blocks connected by the spring . In this frameas in absence of external forces $ V _ { cm } $ cannot change and hence we have :- [image] using this we can see that the springs must compress so as to conserve the energy of the system .

Comment: Let me know if you find this to be wrong I would love to improve the answer !

Comment: Also I would like to point out you didn't mention  if the third block is removed after collision or not if not then I must tell you there would  be a possibility of further collisions .

Comment: In the frame of the center of mass the velocity of the center of mass is always zero. No matter what forces act on the system. This is true for any coordinate system. It will be so no matter what the spring does (it compresses or not), The velocity of the origin of the coordinate system A in the coordinate system A is zero. By definition.

Comment: But you should also notice that the attached blocks perform seperate shm's

Comment: The collision is elastic